# how to use if logic in xslt

Tags: xml, object, xslt, if-statement

I have an xslt that takes and formats an xml, in my code I want to program the logic in case a link element is not present. In such a case i just want to write out the title no link. But I am not getting it to work, perhaps there is a better method. See snippet of code:

EDIT: Added xml, also the if's are left blank and same test because I just have no clue how to fix.

```html
<td>
  <xsl:if test="link=">
    <!-- Look for link, target to blank, the link text is the tittle pulled from xml -->
    <a href="{link}" target="_blank">
      <xsl:value-of select="title" />
    </a>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="link=">
    <xsl:value-of select="title" />
  </xsl:if>
</td>
```

An xml fragment to show how the data comes in.

```html
<movies>

  <!-- 1 -->
  <movie>
    <movieID>0108052</movieID>

    <title>Schindler's List</title>

    <director>Steven Spielberg</director>

    <year>1993</year>

    <genre>Biography,</genre>
    <genre>Drama,</genre>
    <genre>History</genre>


    <link>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108052/</link>
  </movie>
  <movies>
```

Comment: What does your input look like? I would expect `link[=]` to be an element or attribute, not literal text. (The reason your attempt does not work, by the way, is because you do the exact same test twice.)

Comment: @Jongware I added some information there, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for the `xsl:if test=..` statement is wrong. Here it is not a *string* test but an *element* test, so it will try to find an element called `<link=>` – which is actually an invalid element name in XML.

You can simply test (no pun intended) with

```
<xsl:if test="link">there is a child element called "link"</xsl:if>
```

and

```
<xsl:if test="not(link)">there is no child element called "link"</xsl:if>
```

.. but XSLT is very literal-minded, and so you still might not get what you *want*. Suppose your input file contains empty `<link>` elements, such as

```
<link></link>
```

or (more insidious)

```
<link>
</link>
```

– which is "more insidious" because the element actually contains data.

So a better test is against *both* the presence of an element `<link>` *and* whether or not it actually contains textual data instead of only whitespace. Fortunately, you can use the `normalize-space` function to first discard all whitespace and then test if there is anything left. The following template does that:

```
<xsl:template match="movie">
<td>
  <xsl:if test="normalize-space(link)">
    <!-- Look for link, target to blank, the link text is the tittle pulled from xml -->
    <a href="{link}" target="_blank">
      <xsl:value-of select="title" />
    </a>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="not(normalize-space(link))">
    <xsl:value-of select="title" />
  </xsl:if>
</td>
</xsl:template>
```

If you have more than one option to test against, you can chain them in both `<xsl:if>` sequences, but you have to remember to insert all options in both statements, or you may get a double output of `title`. A more versatile solution is to use a list of options:

```
<xsl:template match="movie">
<td>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(link)">
        <!-- Look for link, target to blank, the link text is the tittle pulled from xml -->
        <a href="{link}" target="_blank">
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
        </a>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</td>
</xsl:template>
```

You can add `<xsl:when>` lines for each case, and only if none of them match, it'll automatically fall through to the default `otherwise` action, which merely writes out the title.